# How to redirect by using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have on log in page if user enters both user name and password same then i have to forward user to next page how is it possible.

how do i do this?

Comment: what about, i don't know, authentication?

Comment: Which is your server side language?

Comment: i am just using xhtml along with jquery there is no server side data involve in authentication for presentation purpose i just need to show

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
window.location = '/next-page';
```

Plain JS...

Comment: Just answering the question, can't help any further without JS and PHP code. (assuming PHP)

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you can do this in the server side language itself. You will be validating the user credentials using a server side language and if that evaluates to success then you can redirect the page to a new one from there itself. No need to do this in javascript.

Comment: i need to do at client side for presentation purpose.

Comment: then you can go for `window.location` as mentioned by @webarto.

Answer (score 1):

have some server side authentication in PHP and if that succeeds, use client side stuff (jquery or JS) to redirect

Comment: i don't want to do any server side authentication only client side by using jquery.

Comment: what kind of authentication? it might be easily bypassible then

Comment: just do an onsubmit() function for the submit button of said form which calls some validator function that was previously defined

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");