# Redirection from HTML page to PHP page using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to redirect by using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655535/how-to-redirect-by-using-jquery)

In my site I want to redirect a user from HTML page to PHP page using jQuery.

How can I do this?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why use jQuery? Just plain JavaScript:

```
window.location='http://url.to.my/page.php'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(location).attr('href',"MyPhpPage.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

You you can :)

```
$(location).attr('href',"MyPhpPage.php");
```